# Gitlab gives errors for the e2e test cases when locally they pass without any errors

Tags: gitlab, cypress, e2e-testing, cicd

I tried to run my cypress test cases in GitLab CI/CD pipeline and it gives me those errors but they run without any error in my local cypress GUI. The below image shows one error

[image]

This is my cypress e2e test case
[image]

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file
[image]

This is my cypress.json file - the configuration file
[image]

I appreciate your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option would be be add `{force: true}` for your `click()`.

```
cy.contains('register').should('exist').click({force: true})
```

Secondly you have used `.should('exist')` which checks whether the element is present in the DOM or not and not its visibility. So in case if your app makes the element visible in the near future you can use:

```
cy.contains('register').should('be.visible').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think cy.contains('register').should('exist').click({force: true}) will not check the existance of the button.

Comment: `should('exist')` is checking the existence of your element. Once the element is found to exist in DOM it tries to click. But click only happens to visible element, hence you get the error. To make sure it clicks the element irrespective of visibility you can use `force: true`. But if you want to make sure your element is visible you can use `should('be.visible')`

Comment: Thank you for answering again. Why did I found this error only in the GitLab in my local cypress GUI I found no errors.

Comment: One possible reason i could think of is the execution time, so in your local, by the time you click the element, it is visible and the click happens successfully . You can avoid this by adding `should('be.visible')` so that now cypress waits till the time mentioned for `defaultCommandTimeOut` and then if it doesn't find that the element is visible it fails the test and if it finds it, it then moves on to perform `click()`.